# Is there a way to get the camera in a-frame working with threejs properly?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, aframe

Problems can be seen here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQjbB.jpg

Demo and code:

https://jsfiddle.net/dash1/oystuv60/8/

**1. problem** is if I move the camera with the mouse just a little all the lines are "jiggling" instead of being steady. If I only use wasd-control there is no jiggling effect.

**2. problem** is if I drag the mouse to the left or right it won't just turn but also tilt the camera. So I would like to stop that tilting effect and only turn the camera around the x-axis.

My code looks like that:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-entity id="camrig">
        <a-entity camera id="cam" look-controls position="0 0 0"  ></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

and the jscript code for generating the lines:

```
let singleLineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
singleLineGeometry.vertices.push(points[i]);

var linematerial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: "#000000",
    });
    var line = new THREE.LineSegments(singleLineGeometry, linematerial);
    component.object3D.add(line);
```

I also get the camera and the rig in the jscript code with:

```
let camera = document.getElementById('cam');
let camerarig = document.getElementById('camrig');
```

But I use it only for getting/setting position, rotation and setting speed.

Hopefully someone can help me... :)

Comment: I recommend sharing code people can run, debug and suggest solutions. Otherwise people will have a hard time to help. Glitch is great https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: @DiegoMarcos thanks for the advice. https://jsfiddle.net/dash1/oystuv60/8/